# In scala, how can I get the count of elements that never shown in both arrays?

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, diff, intersect

for example, i have array a
`Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)`
array b
`Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4, 5)`
i'd like to count how many elements that only shown in a or b. in this case, it's (1, 1, 4, 5), so the count is 4.

I tried diff, union, intersect, but I couldn't find a combination of them to get the result I want.

Comment: length of the unique values of the diff set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same idea as the other answer, but linear time:

```
 a.iterator.filterNot(b.toSet).size + b.iterator.filterNot(a.toSet).size
```

(`.iterator` to avoid creating intermediate collections)

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try something like this one but this is not good approach, still this will do the trick.

```
a.filterNot(b contains).size + b.filterNot(a contains).size
```